# Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type .when button is pressed running sql query

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, tkinter

I am trying to get a button to have a command which will run my sql query. The query has worked perfectly in the regular IDLE so not really sure what is going wrong here is the code I am using for the button command:

```
b1 = tk.Button(frame, text = "enter", command = button_command)
b1.place(relx = 0.58, rely = 0.25, relwidth = 0.25,relheight = 0.25)
b1.pack()

def button_command():
    date1 = e1.get()
    date2 = e2.get()
    c.execute("""SELECT SUM(cost) as sum_cost
          FROM outflows1
          where date between ? and ?
          """,
          (e1, e2)
          )
    result_one = c.fetchall()[0][0]
    print(result1)
```

so e1 and 2 are entry boxes which the user can enter a date. These work as parameters for the query to select items within the table that lie between those two dates however when the button is pressed it throws this error in the title.

```
c.execute("""SELECT SUM(cost) as sum_cost
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

. I have never seen this error before and im not really sure how to get around it so any help would be great :)

Comment: It is `(date1, date2)` instead of `(e1, e2)`.

Comment: omg I cannot believe I missed this ;p thanks for pointing this out im glad it was more simple than expected lol